# dimension of the quotient space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M_3(R)$ be the space of all $3 * 3 $ real matrices. Let $V \subset M_3(R)$ be the space of symmetric matrices with trace $0$. The dimension of the quotient space $$\frac{M_3(R)}{V}$$ is

a. $6$

b. $5$

c. $4$

d. $3$

The dimension of a symmetric matrix with trace $0$ is $5$. The quotient space will look like this 
$\{V, X+V\}$, where $X$ is the set of all those matrices whose trace is $\ne0$. And I could generate all those matrices by $\{E_{11},E_{12},E_{13},E_{21},E_{22},E_{23},E_{31},E_{32},E_{33}\}$ where

$E_{ij}=\{a_{ij}=1\}$ and rest all elements are $0$. Somewhere from these elements I need to eliminate all those configuraton which leads to trace $0$. How to do that?

Comment: Since $\dim V=5$, and letting $\dim M_3(R)=n$, $\dim\left(M_3(R)/V\right)=n-5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathrm{dim}M_n(\mathbb R) = n^2$ and hence $\mathrm{dim}M_3(\mathbb R) = 9$. It is easy to compute $\mathrm{dim}V = 5$ by applying the rank nullity theorem to the trace map.

Now consider the quotient map $\pi: M_3(\mathbb R) \to M_3(\mathbb R)/V$. Its kernel is $V$ and its image is $M_3(\mathbb R)/V$. Applying the rank nullity theorem once more yields

$$ \mathrm{dim} M_3(\mathbb R)/V = \mathrm{dim}M_3(\mathbb R) - \mathrm{dim}V =  4$$